# How to prevent tree roots from puncturing pond liner?

Tags: tree, pond

I am building a pond using HDPE pond liner. I'd like to plant various trees around the back of the pond, but am concerned the roots will eventually grow and puncture the liner. Is there such a concern? Are there any steps I can take in the design process to minimize this chance?

Comment: Tree roots can break pipes like sewer pipes so avoid them...

Comment: Interested to know where the progress is on this project? I have my own pond and will be   reading all your posts.